# connecting gprs on window mobile and sending the data in C#

Tags: windows-mobile

hi i am really new to the mobile application so just a spoon feeder.but...... i am trying to develop an application where i can send my data to my website from my window mobile.this is my college project.i want to create a quotation base application where user can send a quotation to the website or the data base but could not able to find anything of relevance.can someone help me as i really have no idea how to do it.though have a good programming knowledge about asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you know ASP.NET you have probably worked with Web Services. In Windows Mobile, using .NET Compact Framework, you can create a Web Service client much the same way as you do on other platforms, so I'd say that would be the easiest thing to try first.